# How would I pass object to viewModel with specific property?

Tags: c#, database, model-view-controller, controller, html.dropdownlistfor

Im currently trying to make a deck builder. I want the Deck form to show certain cards that a single user has and not the total list of all cards in database. I currently have a drop down list of all cards in the database the cards have another property to it that has the UsersId when it was added to the collection. I want the drop down list to on pull ones with that users Id.

Here is the controllers action. I'm assuming what I need to do is right here where I get the whole list of cards.

```
public ActionResult New()
        {
            var cards = _context.Cards.ToList();
            var viewModel = new DeckFormViewModel
            {
               Cards = cards
            };
            return View("DeckForm", viewModel);
        }
```

Here is the form.

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("AddCard", "Deck"))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Deck.CardsId)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Deck.CardsId, new SelectList(Model.Cards, "Id", "Name"), "Choose Card", new { @class = "form-control" },  )
    </div>
}
```

This just shows every card added to database regardless of the userId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're telling it to get all of the cards:

```
_context.Cards.ToList()
```

`_context.Cards` refers to the Cards table. It will load the whole table unless you tell it otherwise.

To filter, use [`.Where()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.where), for example:

```
var cards = _context.Cards.Where(c => c.UserId == userId).ToList();
```

This assumes there's a column in the Cards table called `UserId`, and that you have a variable called `userId` with the current user's username.

There more information about querying data using Entity Framework here: [Querying Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/)

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for. I knew it had to be something like that I just couldn't find the syntax for what it would be, and thank you for the link I will be using that!

Comment: @RileyMincic That link is for Entity Framework Core (for ASP.NET Core). If you're using Entity Framework 6 (with non-Core ASP.NET), then be aware that it is different in some cases, but for the most part querying works the same.